# How can I fix type mismatch error on window.moveTo with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, hta

Everything here works just fine on Windows 7. On Windows 10 we get a type mismatch error for the `window.MoveTo intLeft, intTop`.

```
Sub Window_OnLoad
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
        intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
    Next
    intLeft = (intHorizontal - 670) / 2
    intTop = (intVertical - 325) / 2
    window.ResizeTo 670,325
    window.MoveTo intLeft, intTop
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that `intLeft` and `intTop` are integers and not floating-point numbers?

Comment: Apparently they are both Null.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is `objWMIService`. I guess it doesn't work the same in Windows 10.

Here is a function I found that seems to work just fine.

```
array_ScreenRes = GetScreenResolution
intHorizontal = array_ScreenRes(0)
intVertical = array_ScreenRes(1)

Function GetScreenResolution()
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With oIE
        .Navigate("about:blank")
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
        width = .Document.ParentWindow.Screen.Width
        height = .document.ParentWindow.Screen.Height
    End With

    oIE.Quit
    GetScreenResolution = Array(width, height)
End Function
```